# Import javascript files when needed and global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an import function to import javascript files only when needed. My function looks like the following. They are in the `main.js` file and inside the jquery ready wrapper.

```
$(function() {
    function globaltrigger(){
        alert('');
    }

    function $import(src){
        var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElem.setAttribute('src',src);
        scriptElem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElem);
    }
});
```

Let's say we import a javascript file on a mouse click. `$import('newfile.js');`. However, this newly imported file is unable to access the functions in the `main.js` javascript file. For example:

```
// the following function is placed in the newfile.js file
$(function() {
    globaltrigger();
});
```

Any method to make this work?

Comment: That should work. Is `globaltrigger()` really in the global scope, or is it wrapped in window.onload or DOM ready? What error message do you get?

Comment: Are you calling the function after script is fully loaded. When you click the loading is async, so it might be the case that the file is not fully loaded and you are calling the function

Comment: @MrCode `ReferenceError: globaltrigger is not defined` in firebug. Ah, it seems to be wrapped in `window.onload`. Does $import work with onload?

Comment: Have you verified it's in the global scope? `console.log( window.globaltrigger );`

Comment: There's no reason to wait for document ready to define functions. Just remove the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: You're rolling your own script loader but not using the one built into jQuery? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is as I suspected, the `globaltrigger()` function is not in the global scope. It's inside the jQuery DOM ready function, so is not accessible from outside.

Move it into the global scope:

```
function globaltrigger(){
    alert('');
}

$(function(){
    // dom ready stuff
});
```

It's good practice to avoid polluting the global space with lots of variables and functions. You can store your functions/variables under an object which is a simple way of achieving namespaces.

```
var SomeApp = {};

SomeApp.globaltrigger = function(){
    alert('');
};
```

In the external JavaScript you can call it:

```
SomeApp.globaltrigger();
```

This is good because all of your code lives under the `SomeApp` object.

Comment: Yes, your logic sounds very reasonable. But is there any way of accessing inside the DOM ready without moving the `globaltrigger()`?

Comment: Looks good! One question though, performance wise is it better to have functions saved under the window object as the other poster (Amit Joki) has suggested or to have a different object like yours?

Comment: Performance wise there will be no difference, but it's considered good practice to have your functions and variables under one global object because it avoids name collisions with other code, and if you want to distribute your code or publish it, doing this is a must.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM ready creates a closure, making your function limited to only that scope. You can declare your function to be global like this:

```
window.globaltrigger = function(){
    alert('');
}
```

Now the function is truly global and can be called by other scripts.

Comment: Okay this is one solution. Thanks!

Comment: @pewpewlasers, glad to have helped ;)